# Get the value from a cell in various sheets in another workbook

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am attempting to do the following using Excel formulas and not VBA.  I have two workbooks (say WB1 and WB2) and both are open in Excel.  In WB1 I have a sheet with a cell (say `A1`) that can have different codes, part of which is the name of one of the sheets in WB2.  The codes are of the form `DOD8.2x1.9, DOD8.2x2.4...DOD9.2x1.9, DOD9.2x2.4.., DOD10.2x4.9` etc where the characters up to the `x` refer to the sheets in WB2 (i.e. `DOD8.2, DOD9.2, DOD10.2` etc). I need a formula for another cell in WB1 (say `B1`)that can get the value of a specific cell in the sheet in WB2 that is defined by this code.  I know that a formula in `B1` of the form `=[WB2.xlsx]DOD8.2!$EB$6` or `=[WB2.xlsx]DOD10.2!$EB$6` is how to get cell values from specific sheets in WB2 and that the formula `=LEFT(A1, FIND("x",A1)-1)` will extract the relevant part of cell `A1` to give me the name of a specific worksheet in WB2 but I cannot work out how to use this to construct a formula that combines the two to automatically select the worksheet defined by the code in `A1`.  I've tried replacing the sheet name (e.g `DOD10.2`) in the general formula with `LEFT(A1, FIND("x",A1)-1)` so I end up with `=[WB2.xlsx]LEFT(A1, FIND("x",A1)-1)!$EB$6` using different concatenation methods but none work.  Can anyone suggest a way of achieving this?

Comment: Research the INDIRECT formula.

Comment: Thank you for the tip.  I've tried this `=(INDIRECT("[WB2.xlsx]"&"(LEFT(A1, FIND(""x"",A1)-1))"&"!"&"$EB$6"))`  and this `=[WB2.xlsx]&"INDIRECT(LEFT(A1, FIND(""x"",A1)-1))"&"!$EB$6"` but get a `#REF!` error for the first and a `Formula problem` with the second.  Am I correct to be trying to build a character string of the formula?

Answer (score 0):

You are very close.

Assume you have workbook `WB2` containing three worksheets as you describe: `DOD8.2`, `DOD9.2`, and `DOD10.2`. In cell A1 of each sheet there are the text values `foo`, `bar`, and `baz`, respectively.

In spreadsheet `WB1` you can access these three values as follows:

```
=INDIRECT(CONCAT("[WB2.xlsx]", LEFT(A1, FIND("x",A1)-1), "!$A$1"))
```

For example:

[image]

The `concat` function builds a string representing the referent to the required sheet in `WB2`. The `indirect` function then interprets that string as an actual cell reference, and displays the contents of the cell.

If you prefer using `&` instead of `concat`, then you can use this:

```
=INDIRECT("[WB2.xlsx]" & LEFT(A1, FIND("x",A1)-1) & "!$A$1")
```

Comment: I managed to work it out myself as well using `&` but was unaware of the `concat` function.which I will use in future.  Thanks